# c++ checking an array for a specific range of values?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

i would like to check an array for a specific range of values.
ie, the range of values is from 0 --> 9 and the actual array is 50 elements large.

i also want to keep track of how many of each value there is.
ie, if there are 3 zeroes, 8 ones and 5 two's, then my final vector should look like, 3 8 5.

i was able to solve it with the code below BUT, i realized that my range values needs to be equal to my array size, otherwise it does not check all elements.

is there a better way to do this?

```
int main() {

int intensityRange = 10;
int cloudSize = 10;

int cloud [] = {0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2};
vector <int> totalGreyValues;
int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < intensityRange; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < cloudSize; j++) {
      if (cloud[j] == i) {
         k = k + 1;
         cout << "   " << k;
      }
      else
        cout << "  no match  ";
   }
   totalGreyValues.push_back (k);
   k = 0;
}

cout << endl << endl << totalGreyValues.size();

for (int h = 0; h < totalGreyValues.size(); h ++)
   cout << "   " << totalGreyValues[h];

// values --> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
// answer --> 1 1 3 3 0 2 0 0 0 0 

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's much easier to use `std::map`:

```
int size = 50;
int data[size] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... };

std::map<int, int> mymap;

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
   if(data[i] >= min && data[i] <= max)
      mymap[data[i]] = mymap[data[i]] + 1;
}
```

This saves some space, because you don't save unused values and the loop count is also much smaller, because you only process once per value.

Comment: damn! I was almost done writing the same code to solve this! upvote for you sir.

Comment: :D I felt like there was somebody who also answers this question so I sped up a little bit.

Comment: thanks for that!
being a noob, i don't really follow the if statement. i assume that min and max are the intensityRange in my code BUT how does it check for each value in between? looks like its just checking for a min and max value and not each value in between....or?

Comment: you are right min and max are the range, but it doesn't check for each value because it doesn't need to thanks to `std::map`. e.g. with this method you write `mymap[8] = 1;` and it automatically creates a int which you can use as a counter for your value (8 here) which you increment with each further check. Later you just iterate through all the saved counters and values.

Comment: Using a map is only useful if the histogram is sparsely populated. If a majority of elements in the range are likely to be populated, use a vector initialised to the length of the range. Maps are relatively expensive data structures.

Comment: It would be better to use a multiset, which has builtin-support for exactly what you are doing manually and with unneeded spatial overhead. Another recommendation: You are indexing into the map twice; you can make it with just one lookup.

Answer (score 0):

If your range is continuous I would prefer a [boost::vector_property_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/property_map/vector_property_map.html).

```
#include <boost/property_map/vector_property_map.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  boost::vector_property_map<unsigned int> m(10); // size of expected range

  std::vector<int> cloud = {0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2};
  for(auto x : cloud) { m[x]++; }
  for(auto it = m.storage_begin(); it != m.storage_end(); ++it) { 
    std::cout << *it << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If your range does not start at `0` you can use `IndexMap` template
argument to remap the indices. This will also work if you map a non
continous set of values that you want to count into a continous
range. You might need to perform a check if you only want to count
specific values, but given the expensiveness of the count operation,
I'd rather count them all instead of checking what to count.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::map` and the `std::accumulate` function:

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::map<int, int> Histogram;

Histogram& addIfInRange(Histogram& histogram, const int value)
{
    if(inRange(value))
    {
        ++histogram[value];
    }
    // else don't add it

    return histogram;
}

Histogram histogram =
    std::accumulate(data, data + size, Histogram(), addIfInRange);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have large enough empty regions, you can try a multiset, together with some of C++' new facilities:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    int vals[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6 };

    std::multiset <int> hist;
    for (auto const &v : vals)
        if (v >= 3 && v <= 5) hist.insert (v);

    for (auto const &v : hist)
        std::cout << v << " -> " << hist.count (v) << '\n';
}
```

If your data is densely populated, a `std::vector` might give superiour results:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    using std::begin; using std::end;

    int vals[] = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6 };

    const auto val_mm  = std::minmax_element (begin(vals), end(vals));
    const int  val_min = *val_mm.first,
               val_max = *val_mm.second + 1;

    std::vector<int> hist (val_max - val_min);

    for (auto v : vals)
        ++hist [v - val_min];

    for (auto v : vals)
        std::cout << v << " -> " << hist[v-val_min] << '\n';
}
```